# accidentally deleted efi partition and can not install new system from usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I accidentally deleted several partitions on my Thinkpad T460s with ubuntu 14.04 installed(alongside with OEM windows 7) using GParted, and no system (neither ubuntu or windows boot manager) could be booted afterward. There is even no grub interface after power on.

```
/dev/sda3 is windows
/dev/sda4 is something unknown (must be home?)
/dev/sda5 is /root for ubuntu
/dev/sda7 is swap
```

However, It is possible to go to the grub interface only by booting from my mobile hard drive and then executing `set prefix=(hd1,gpt5)/boot/grub` and `set root=(hd1,gpt5)` and `insmod normal` and finally `normal` could lead me to the Ubuntu system.

But using a normal usb stick could only lead to installing or trying ubuntu 18.40? but not leading to the grub interface, Why?

After entering the existing Ubuntu system, I used GParted to create a partition named EFI on `/dev/sda2`.
but  trying to install ubuntu fails with the error

```
[0,000000][firmware bug]:TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version:0xb2(or later)
[6,907994] tpm tpm0: A TPM error(6) occured attempting to read a pcr value
[208,659418] SQUASHFS error: sqaushfs_read_data failed to read block 0x109abf19
```

and there are more errors which are eliminated.

my UEFI BIOS version is `N1CET47W (1.15)`
Anyone knows what to do? 
Thanks!

Edit:
 Now I did something more dangerous,after booting into live mode,  I use GParted to completely resized all my parition
now

```
sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Crucial_CT525MX3 (scsi)
Diask /dev/sda 525GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Diask Flags:
NUMBER START EDN SIZE FILE sYSTEM nAME FLAGS
1               17.4KB  134mb     -      --                         MSFTRES
2               135MB    240MB  105MB   FAT32     -   MSFTDATA
3               317gb     481gb   164gb  ext4    basic data partition msftdata
warning: the driver descriptor says the phsical block size is 2048 bytes, but LInux says it is 512 byte. Ignore/cancel?
```

Now I can not even execute the install ubuntu icon or directly install ubuntu. Since it will always halts at the ubuntu starting screen but never change.

Comment: While you're in live Ubuntu run `sudo parted -l` and post output, as that will give some idea what you have and what partitions are missing. You should not need to create an EFI partition. If you deleted it then run [boot-repair](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) which should re-create your grub on your HDD. Whether you can boot from grub to Ubuntu or Windows depends on what partitions you deleted.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from vendor for your system? Was Windows installed in UEFI boot mode? Most Windows 7 systems were BIOS, a only a few are UEFI. Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: You said sda3 is Windows. But according to your output it shows 'data', not Windows. Unless you've omitted part of the output, it looks like it's been wiped. In Gparted/edit you can undo the last operation, but I suspect things have gone too far. Nothing showing for sda5 either, so no Ubuntu? If you backed up images of Windows and Ubuntu, you can easily retrieve the situation from them. Otherwise your only hope is to boot into live Ubuntu, and download Testdisk and try to retrieve the situation from that.